# Moving incremental average

Tags: c++, algorithm, moving-average

I am writing a function in C++ to calculate the moving average of a data stream. I want to use [incremental averaging](http://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/calculating-the-average-incrementally/) . As am implementing this on a relatively weak microprocessor I want to perform a moving average. That is, I want to perform an incremental average over the last X values (X ~ 100).

As I understand it, incremental averaging requires all data to be averaged and does not support a moving window.

Does anyone know a good way to calculate the "moving" incremental average?

Comment: [Select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A(i, n)` is the average over the n elements `x_i, ..., x_(i + n - 1)`, then `A(i + 1, n) = A(i, n) + (x_(i +n) - x_i) / n`.

Comment: You gave a formula for the "global" average, not the moving average as asked.